# HTML5, Adding custom fonts

Tags: css, html

I am new at learning HTML5 and CSS. Advanced apology for this very basic question.
I have downloaded a font and saved it in a folder called fonts in my project. 
Then created a fonts.css file inside of css folder and put the following code in it.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FiraCode-Regular';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FireCoda-Light';
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/FireCoda-Light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/FireCoda-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/FireCoda-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/FireCoda-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/FireCoda-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Then in the main.css file I added the following css:

```
body{
 font-family:"FiraCode-Regular",Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

here is an screen shot of the file hierarchy in my project
[image]

now the problem is the font is not working. I would appreciate if anyone can help me here.

Comment: bugler's errors let's

Comment: Silly question, but are you actually importing the fonts.css stylesheet so that the styles contained are available (either inline in your HTML or via a CSS @import in main.css)?

Comment: is it now working?

Comment: @Delinear, I had imported it, but I just realized that there was a problem with my HTML , I think the order that I imported my normalize.css, main.css and font.css was wrong so I fixed those.

Comment: @caramba: thank you for your help due. It is working now. But due to the reasons I explained to Delinear. Apparently order of the css file are some how important.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
@import url("./fonts.css");
```

in your `main.css` as the first line.